# rails array of json, rotate one value

Tags: arrays, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an JSON array as follows:

```
arr = [
  {day: 1, hour:1, value: 143}, 
  {day: 1, hour:2, value: 243}, 
  {day: 1, hour:3, value: 100},
  {day: 1, hour:4, value: 113}
]
```

and given some integer value, I want to be able to rotate the **value** field in this array that integer amount So if I rotated clockwise 1 time, then I should get:

```
arr = [
  {day: 1, hour:1, value: 113}, 
  {day: 1, hour:2, value: 143}, 
  {day: 1, hour:3, value: 243}, 
  {day: 1, hour:4, value: 100}
]
```

The last element just becomes the first, etc etc

I am new to rails and have no idea how to accomplish this. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `i` is the number of times you want to rotate. You could do this:

```
i.times do 
  arr.unshift(arr.pop)
end
```

Comment: Sorry I'm an idiot. I totally typed this in incorrectly.  I only want to shift the **value** field and keep everything else the same. Any ideas?